# How should I train my Keras stateful LSTM on very long, disjointed sequences?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a very long sequence (~ 5 million rows) of multivariate data for which I need to make a prediction of a single value at each time step. The sequences are disjointed though, in the sense that they are continuous for several tens of thousands of lines, and then the data will jump ahead by a few thousand time steps. I want to preserve the state across batches (using a stateful LSTM), but reset the state if the time skips ahead by a certain amount.

My initial idea was to use Keras `train_on_batch` method to do this using this approximate structure:

```
model.Sequential()
... # build the model

for epoch in range(epochs):
    current_time = 0
    previous_time = 0
    for batch in range(n_batches):
        (input, labels) = nextBatch() 
        current_time = input['time']
        if current_time - previous_time > 1000:
            model.reset_states() # reset state if time jump is > 1000
        model.train_on_batch(input, labels)
```

Is this generally the right approach? I've also considered using `fit_generator` but I'm not aware of any way to reset the states during training with this method.

Comment: I think this is the only way.

Comment: Are you predicting "the future"? Or just values related with existing steps?

Comment: I need to predict the labels for all time steps up to the present time.